# How do I loop through column names to compute statistics?

Tags: r, loops, variables, names

say I have data that looks like this

```
rating  repair  model
5        0       1
4        0       0 
2        1       1
5        1       0
```

I want to be able to find the mean of rating for every time repair ==1. However I actually have 200 column names I want to do this for that do not follow a specific pattern. I do not know how to loop through these columns. I know that

```
 mean(dt[dt$repair==1,]$rating, na.rm=T)
```

will get me what i want but not how to loop through. The following doesn't seem to work. Thanks!

```
for(name in rep_names){
    dt[paste0('dt$',name)==1,]$rating
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find `mean` for all columns when `repair == 1` we can use `summarize_all` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>%
 filter(repair == 1) %>%
 summarize_all(~mean(., na.rm = TRUE))

# rating repair model
#1    3.5      1   0.5
```

---

In base R, we can also use `colMeans`

```
colMeans(dt[dt$repair == 1,], na.rm = TRUE)

#rating repair  model 
#   3.5    1.0    0.5
```

---

**EDIT**

As mentioned in comments if there are number of columns which we need to filter for 1 and then take the mean we can first select those columns using column index or column name. For example, let's assume we want to filter columns 2 to 3 here, then we can do

```
rep_names <- 2:3
colMeans(df[rowSums(df[rep_names] == 1) == length(rep_names), ])

#rating repair  model 
# 2      1      1
```

`rep_names` can contain column number of column names which we want to check for 1's.

Comment: Thanks for the answers but the problem is I actually have 100+ columns with a variety of names and I want to find the average of the rating column such for when column 1 ==1, column 2==1 etc. not just repair==1. so I need to loop through the names of the 100+ columns

Comment: @Megan I have updated the answer accordingly, please check if that is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`, we can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[repair == 1, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = TRUE)]
#   rating repair model
#1:    3.5      1   0.5
```

#### Update

Based on the comments

```
setDT(df1)[column1 == 1 & column2 == 1, lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = 3:ncol(df1)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers but the problem is I actually have 100+ columns with a variety of names and I want to find the average of rating such for when column 1 ==1, column 2==1 etc. not just repair==1.

Comment: thanks @akrun! so do I still have to type out each column name though? I have over 150 so I was hoping not to have to do that...

Comment: @Megan I put the index of columns `3:ncol(df1)` if you have noticed in the `.SDcols`

Answer (score 1):

An `apply` solution. Might be slow:

```
apply(df[df["repair"]==1,],2,mean)
# rating repair  model 
#   3.5    1.0    0.5
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers but the problem is I actually have 100+ columns with a variety of names and I want to find the average of the rating column such for when column 1 ==1, column 2==1 etc. not just repair==1. so I need to loop through the names of the 100+ columns